# How to include multiple PWA inside an apk?

Tags: android, apk, progressive-web-apps, trusted-web-activity

I am trying to develop a app which will be a one stop destination for various ecommerce apps and social networking apps. Ofcourse all that apps are PWA, however these PWA has to be integrated inside the primary apk with designated icons for each PWA.

I tried implementing imageview with url of the PWA and adding intent to it. It still shows address bar.

I dont want to use webview as it has limited functionality, i want to use the potential of PWA inside apk(when the pwa opens it should not show address bar). Did you achieve this in your project? If so, how did you implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup Digital Asset Links for each origin opened inside the Trusted Web Activity. In summary:

1. each origin will need its own `/.well-known/assetlinks.json` file.
2. each origin needs to be listed in `asset_statements` inside the Android app.
3. additional origins need to be passed to the `TrustedWebActivityIntentBuilder` before launching.

You can find full deatails on the [official guide on how to implement multi-origin Trusted Web Activity](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity/multi-origin)